# SUM(…) OVER (ORDER BY …) in view causes poor performance

Tags: sql, view, sum, sql-server-2016, window-functions

I've got a view defined that lists transactions together with a running total, something like

```
CREATE VIEW historyView AS
    SELECT
        a.createdDate,
        a.value,
        m.memberId,
        SUM(a.value) OVER (ORDER BY a.createdDate) as runningTotal,
        ...many more columns...
        FROM allocations a
        JOIN member m ON m.id = a.memberId
        JOIN ...many joins...
```

The biggest tables this query looks at have ~10 million rows, but on average when the view is queried it will only return a few tens of rows.

My issue is that when this `SELECT` statement is run directly for a given member, it executes extremely quickly and returns results in a couple of milliseconds. However, when queried as a view...

```
SELECT h.createdDate, h.value, h.runningTotal
    FROM historyView h
    WHERE member.username = 'blah@blah.com'
```

...the performance is dreadful. The two query plans are very different - in the first case it is pretty much ideal but in the latter case, there are loads of scans and hundreds of thousands/millions of rows being read. This is clearly because the filter on member is being run last thing after everything else has been done, rather than right up front at the start.

If I remove the `SUM(x) OVER (ORDER BY y)` clause, this problem goes away.

Is there something I can do to ensure that the `SUM(x) OVER (ORDER BY y)` clause does not ruin the query plan?

Comment: This is how views tend to be optimized.  It is a shame.  You might have better luck with an inline table-valued function.

Comment: That is a shame! Unfortunately the queries against this view are generated by some OData middleware that will be filtering on all sorts of things, so I'm not sure a TVF would work

Comment: Welcome to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to my problem is to let the query optimiser know it is safe to filter *before* running the windowed function by `PARTITION`'ing by that property. The change to the view is:

```
CREATE VIEW historyView AS
    SELECT
        a.createdDate,
        a.value,
        m.memberId,
        SUM(a.value) OVER (PARTITION BY m.username ORDER BY a.createdDate) as runningTotal,
        ...many more columns...
        FROM allocations a
        JOIN member m ON m.id = a.memberId
        JOIN ...many joins...
```

Unfortunately this only creates the correct plan if filtering my member's username is part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

That's because there's probably an index on `m.username`.  When it comes to query tuning it takes some trial and error. 
When using window functions there is the concept of 'POC' index to take into consideration - just search on google (Itzik Ben-Gan has good references about this as well).
From the book 'High-Performance T-SQL Using Window Functions':

> Absent a POC index, the plan includes a Sort iterator, and with large input sets, it can be quite
>   expensive. Sorting has N * LOG(N) complexity, which is worse than linear. This means that with more
>   rows, you pay more per row. For example 1000 * LOG(1000) = 3000 and 10000 * LOG(10000) =
>   40000. This means that 10 times more rows results in 13 times more work, and it gets worse the further you go.

Here's a reference [link](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/sql-server-2012-how-write-t-sql-window-functions-part-3) to get started on window functions and indexes.